# Hyperledger Fabric: Failed to update ordering service endpoints, due to Channel with mychannel id was not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we see this error in our peer logs and don't know what to do about it. Is this something we should ignore?

```
2019-03-19 18:03:03.472 UTC [gossip/service] updateEndpoints -> WARN a8d Failed to update ordering service endpoints, due to Channel with mychannel id was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning seems to be coming from following piece of code and looks like can be ignored:

```
func (g *gossipServiceImpl) updateEndpoints(chainID string, endpoints []string) {
    if ds, ok := g.deliveryService[chainID]; ok {
        logger.Debugf("Updating endpoints for chainID", chainID)
        if err := ds.UpdateEndpoints(chainID, endpoints); err != nil {
            // The only reason to fail is because of absence of block provider
            // for given channel id, hence printing a warning will be enough
            logger.Warningf("Failed to update ordering service endpoints, due to %s", err)
        }
    }
```

if the peer is not a leader in the channel then it doesn't have an entry in the map